# Trying to reach Angular Universal (SSR) route gives 404 (Cannot Get)

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I have created an SSR Angular app which I like to reach from an api or postman.
I need the html generated from the SSR app.

The routings for the app is as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'test',
  component: TestComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/test` in Chrome I am succesfully routet to `TestComponent` and the content is shown

If I enter the root of the angular app (`http://localhost:4200`) in Postman I get a 200 and the html is shown as a response.

**But** if I enter the test route in postman (`http://localhost:4200/test`) I get a 404 and the content in the response is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /test</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

**What am I missing here? I haven't configured any proxy and I am not trying to hit an api route either.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4200 is the port for client side development.

If you want to test that SSR works correctly, you need to use the port specified in your `server.ts` file, which I think is 4000 by default

```
http://localhost:4000/test
```

Note: I'm not sure why, but I found that to access the a specific route on client app (port 4200) using Postman you need to add the `Accept` header in Postman.

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
```

With that header set, you should be able to reach http://localhost:4200/test using Postman, but once again you will not be testing SSR with that port

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that the SSR effect was only working when served from the server. Running serve worked and I am now able to get the response from postman.

Comment: Wow, that's quite misleading - I did not expect the 404 response to be an issue an incorrect Accept-header. I was sure there was something wrong with my angular setup. A response code like 412 would be more clear imo.